# C++- does map sort by key, and then value?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I understand that the map type in C++ automatically sorts its entries by the key. However, how does it handle breaking ties? Does it then sort according to value?

Comment: You mean an `std::multimap`? A usual map does not have duplicate keys. Also, it's not sorted in a usual sense, instead, it's a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

Comment: `std::map` does not have duplicate keys, so if there is a tie the keys are considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator for C++ map and multimap only sees the keys, not the values.  There is no need to "break ties": two keys are considered equal if and only if neither one compares less than the other.